# XML parsing in Go for same tags under different parent tag

Tags: xml, go, struct, xml-parsing

I am new to Go, and I am trying to parse an XML file.  My goal is to get the values of all the config tags by making only one structure for them. Not a separate structure for each parent tag. Below is the XML file and what I have done.

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <TestFramework>
        <config>
            <name>TEST_COMPONENT</name>
            <value>FILMS</value>
            <description>
           Name of the test Films.
            </description>
        </config>
        <config>
            <name>TESTER_NAME</name>
            <value>abc@xyz.com</value>
            <description>
            Name or email of the tester.
            </description>
        </config>
    </TestFramework>
    <Product>
        <config>
            <name>PRODUCT_RELEASE</name>
            <value>2.1</value>
            <description>
            Name or email of the tester.
            </description>
        </config>
        <config>
            <name>PRODUCT_BUILD</name>
            <value>7.1.3182018</value>
            <description>
            Name or email of the tester.
            </description>
        </config>
    </Product>
</root>
```

My Go program:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

type ConfigFile struct {
    Configs []Config `xml:"config"`
}

type Config struct {
    Name  string `xml:"name"`
    Value string `xml:"value"`
}

func main() {
    xmlFile, err := os.Open("octa_config.xml")
    m := make(map[string]string)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }else {
        fmt.Println("Successfully Opened octa_config.xml")
    }
    defer xmlFile.Close()
    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)
    var c ConfigFile
    xml.Unmarshal(byteValue,&c)
    for i := 0; i < len(c.Configs); i++ {
        m[c.Configs[i].Name]=c.Configs[i].Value
    }
    for k,v :=range m{
        fmt.Println( k,v)
    }
}
```

I know I can make a struct like this:

```
type TestFramework struct {
    Configs []Config `xml:"TestFramework>config"`
}
```

But I don't want to use this:

```
`xml:"TestFramework>config"`
```

I am getting output like this:

```
D:\Go>go run config_nim.go
Successfully Opened octa_config.xml

D:\Go>
```

Comment: The struct representing your config does not match the structure of the XML tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `,any` tag option.

```
type root struct {
    XMLName xml.Name     `xml:"root"`
    Files   []ConfigFile `xml:",any"`
}

type ConfigFile struct {
    Configs []Config `xml:"config"`
}

type Config struct {
    Name        string `xml:"name"`
    Value       string `xml:"value"`
    Description string `xml:"description"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/osaA5t5BnHi